# Radio Button Flutter

Tags: flutter, radio-button

I am getting this error when i use Radio Button.

```
int _value = 1;
```

```
error: A value of type 'int?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'. (invalid_assignment at \[coacum_01\] lib/match_screen.dart:450)
```

[image]

[image]

Honestly i don't know what to do, so i did not tried any thing.What can i try?

Answer (score 2):

It's due to null safety.
You are trying to assign a nullable integer **int?** to a non-nullable integer **int**, which is not allowed in Dart.
To solve this error, you can either change the data type of the variable **val** to int to make it non-nullable, or make sure that the value being assigned to _value is not null using **_value = val!**
Alternatively, you can use the null-aware assignment operator **??=** to assign a default value to _value in case it is null, like this: **_value = val ?? 0**
(only if datatype is **int?**)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `_value` nullable, by doing `int? _value = 1;`, or you can guarantee that `val` has a value when you `setState`, by doing `_value = val ?? -1;` which will set `_value` to `-1` if `val == null`.